# Check if Axios has a session cookie

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm implementing a navigation guard for my Vue.js application, checking whether the user is logged in. I think the best way would be to ask Axios if it has a session cookie or not. Something like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (Vue.axios.hasSessionCookie())
    next()
  else
    next(false);
}
```

Except, of course, `hasSessionCookie()` doesn't exist, and I don't see anything like it in the docs. Is there a way, maybe by some extension?

Yes, I know I could store the login status in the VueX store. I don't think it's a good idea because the state would reset if the user, in his infinite wisdom, refreshed the page and thus reset the application. Another solution I have in mind is a backend endpoint where the app can "ask" if it's logged in. But that's also quite lame.

Comment: How do you set the cookie on the first place? Is it from client-side cookie using `document.cookies`?

Comment: It's a session cookie coming from the Node.js / Express backend. Axios catches it and the session works. But there seems to be no way to ask Axios whether it has a session cookie or not.

Comment: If it's a server-side session cookie, then there's no way to check it from client-side javascript, you need to make an extra HTTP request to your express server to check if the sever-side session cookie valid / exists.

Comment: You mean there's no way to validate it. I don't want to validate, only check if a session exists. It's for a frontend navigation guard, not something critical.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(document.cookie)` on your web via developer console and see if your cookie value is there?

Comment: It's not there.

Comment: Then it's a server-side cookie, and since the cookie session is stored in server-side, you can't check it from  client-side javascript, and as I said before, you need to send a HTTP request to your express server just to check if the cookie is exist on server side.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all the tips. The right solution was the following:

- VueX stores the login status (simply a Boolean flag) which the navigation guard checks
- When the user logs in or out, I set the flag
- When the app launches, I call the `/checklogin` route on the server before the Vue instance is created. This simply returns a 200 or a 401 status code depending on whether the user has a valid session or not. Then I set the VueX flag accordingly. This way the user can refresh the browser but VueX will still know if he's logged in or not.
- Plus I added an Axios interceptor to detect 401 errors. If there is one, it means the session has expired. It then sets the VueX flag to `false` and redirects the user to the login page.

I wrote an article on my Medium blog with details and snippets if anyone cares.
https://medium.com/developer-rants/session-management-between-express-and-axios

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a server-side cookie, you can't check it on client-side javascript, you need to make a HTTP request to your express server to check if session exists. Create a simple route on your express server like this:

```js
app.get("/checkcookie", function(req,res) {
    if (req.session.yourSessionVariableName) {
        res.status(204).send();
    } else {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
});
```

Then check on your vue navigation guard:

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://yourexpressbackend.com/checkcookie");
  if (response.status === 204)
    next()
  else
    next(false);
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now. But it's not a very good solution: it's one extra HTTP call every time the user changes route, meaning extra burden on the server, and it slows down the app too. I think I'm settling with storing a flag in the VueX store and whenever Axios gets a 401, set it to false.

Comment: You need to "frankenstein" it a bit if you want to check it on the client-side like the way you said. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42472973/12397250) as it might be useful. If you want a good solution to check user authentication on client-side then you need to use store your authentication information (token, JWT, etc.) in client-side like localStorage or client-side cookie.

Comment: Thanks, I think I already found a solution. I'm going to write a post about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction but axios is a HTTP client and it has nothing to do with cookies neither do it care about cookies or storage.. so you need use a package like [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) to set and get cookies.

Comment: Alas it won't help. IDK what does Axios do with the cookies, but the session cookie doesn't show up in Developer Tools and can't be read with vue-cookies. The backend definitely delivers it.

Answer (score 0):

Tamás Polgár, you documented the same exact challenge I had with Vue; what to do with login if an unexpected browser event happens and the store is lost.

**The Vue store:**

The Vue store is meant to be a convenient location for an SPA to store such a flag (logged in or not), however, the store is completely erased and re-established with each Vue instance, which means a new browser window / tab, refresh, or other unexpected event that triggers a browser refresh.

So your approach describes an extra back-end call to quickly check the status, which is a legit and work-able solution IMO.

There are also two more potential solutions, the second of which of which I've implemented in my own SPA:

**Two Other Solutions**

**1)** Don't touch your back end code at all.  Use [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) to have the client browser set a cookie once a login has been established (this would be completely separate from the http-only cookie that the back-end API server needs).

This cookie *should* still exist after a browser refresh.  I did not use (or try) this approach, however, as I didn't want to mess around with altering my front-end to check a local cookie each time I want to check for login status.

The front end code could use this cookie to figure out if the person is still logged in or not.

**2)** Another, separate approach is to short-circuit the normal back-end API check for authentication *only for that specific route's controller*, but not for any other route.

Here's how a 'short-circuit' on the back-end would work:

In the case of that specific route's controller method, have it first check for existence of the user in the request, and then **return a 200 but with a status of "false" or some other variable which also appears in the success response.**

It's counter-intuitive, but this gives the front end Axios call something to grab onto other than just a standard error response.

**NOTE**: I call it a "short-circuit" because if the back-end API route's controller method has a lot of code, making this check the FIRST thing it does will avoid the costly part of the call.

This approach works perfectly for my needs and doesn't require a new or secondary API call.

Comment: Indeed it's somewhat counter-intuitive to check the backend, but as things are in *the current year* I have a feeling that we've long abandoned concepts like elegant and smooth coding. Particularly in the Javascript world.